# enclosing csv fields with quotes

Tags: php, csv

i need to enclose my data in " " already tried several things but i only mess up my data

i need the output csv to be formated:
"data","data","data" 
the code im using and displayed below was copied from another question here.

```
if (($handle = fopen('DIRTY_'.$val['spider'].'.csv', 'r')) !== false) {
    // read each line into an array
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8192, ",")) !== false) {
        // build a "line" from the parsed data
        $line = join("," , $data );

        // if the line has been seen, skip it
        if (isset($lines[$line])) continue;

        // save the line
        $lines[$line] = true;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}


$contents = '';
foreach ($lines as $line => $bool) $contents .= $line . "\r\n";


file_put_contents($val['spider'].".csv", $contents);
```

}

Comment: Where is your code that does this? What do you want to do if the field contains quotes?

Comment: sorry i didnt explaines well  in eed to output csv to have the fields in the following  format 
"data","data","data"

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) and [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv). It will do escaping for you.

It's also worth mentioning that CSV is not a well defined standard. Sometimes it's comma separated, sometimes it's semicolons and sometimes it's tabs. Sometimes `"` are always present, sometimes only when you have newlines.